# syntax error at or near ":" when running parametrized query from shell

Tags: postgresql, shell, psql

I'm trying to run a parameterized query from shell.

But when I run:

```
p='some stuff'
psql -d "dbname" -v v1="$p" -c "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name=:'v1'"
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near ":"
```

Meanwhile:

```
psql -d "dbname" -v v1="$p" -c "\echo :'v1'"
```

works normally. (returns as expected: `'some stuff'`)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot use the variable defined in `-v` in `-c` command (see below). Try passing the command into the standard input:

```
psql -d "dbname" -v v1="$p" <<< "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name=:'v1'"
```

From the [document](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/app-psql.html):

> -c command
>
> --command command
>
> ...
>
> **command** must be either a command string that is completely parsable by
>   the server (i.e., ***it contains no psql-specific features***), or a single
>   backslash command.
>
> ...

`-v` does set the psql's internal variable, which is ***psql-specific features***. That's why you got the syntax error.

Comment: thanks, managed to make it work with


`echo "SELECT * FROM table WHERE name=:'v1'" | psql -d "dbname" -v v1="$p"`

Comment: @Blomex Yes sure, pipeline `|` has the same effect as the here-string notation `<<<` (send string into stdin) to run that sql except that it (`psql`) will run in a sub-shell. And an _upvote_ or _accept_ would be very motivating and useful for other readers.